# No update of database with UpdateView django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I know my code is not optimal as I'm only a beginner with Django so don't be too hard on me

Here is my code :

views.py

```
class ComposantUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = configuration
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'accueil/exploitation/update_composant.html'
```

update_composant.html

```
<form action="{% url 'composant_update' pk=composant.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {% for field in form %}
            <label class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 nom_champ"> {{field.label_tag}}</label>
            <input class="col-md-4 offset-md-4 contenu_champ" type="text" name="{{ field.label }}" id="{{ field.id_for_label }}" value="{{ field.value }}"/>
        {%endfor%}
        <br>
        <br>
        <button class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Update" /> Mettre à jour </button>
    </div>  
</form>
```

urls.py

```
path('update_composant/<int:pk>', views.ComposantUpdate.as_view(), 
name='composant_update'),
```

models.py

```
class configuration(models.Model):
    Num_ordre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Composant = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Designation = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Qte_servie = models.IntegerField()
    Qte_a_servir = models.IntegerField()
    Lot = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Categorie  = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Famille = models.CharField(max_length=15)
def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s %s' % (self.Num_ordre, self.Designation, self.Lot)
```

when I go to the url of the form, all the fields get the content of the database which is what I expect but if I modify the "Lot" field and click to submit, my database is not updated at all with the new value of "Lot". DO you have any idea of why ? For information, I do get redirected to the 'composant_update' view and no error is risen

Comment: Aren't you swapping `label` with `name`?

Comment: You forgot to render the eventual form's validation errors in your template. If your form has errors it will be redisplayed without any information about what went wrong. Add the errors back in your form (how to do this is documented in the FineManual and in quite a few articles) and you'll make your life easier - and your app's users happier <g>

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I didn't write my html correctly, the attribute "name" in the input should have been {{field.html_name}} instead of {{field.label}}.

This doesn't work :

```
<input class="col-md-4 offset-md-4 contenu_champ" type="text" name="{{ field.label }}" id="{{ field.id_for_label }}" value="{{ field.value }}"/>
```

This works :

```
<input class="col-md-4 offset-md-4 contenu_champ" type="text" name="{{ field.html_name}}" id="{{ field.id_for_label }}" value="{{ field.value }}"/>
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#s-looping-over-the-form-s-fields for more information

Thanks Willem Van Onsem !